# my Webservice, their XSD. How to integrate them?

Tags: xsd, webservice-client

We have a company that is requesting us to have a webservice in order to interact with our Database.

They sent us a documentation where they state that they need us to respond complying with some Automobile Insurance XSD file.

they have a predefined Soap Request ( I think they as well comply with certain XSD for request).

So at this point i am very confused on how to handle this situation. I have created webservice before but never used any mandatory XSD or specific SOAP Requests.

I have no clue on how to start dealing with this. Anyone can help me understand and get me started?

I am going to post both, the Soap Request they send and the XSD they want us to comply with.

Thank You

Note. Unfortunately i just realized i can't post the XML here. It doesnt shows the markup.

Comment: Do you have a link to the XSD?

Comment: Indent your XML by four spaces (using the `{}` button) to format it on SO.

Comment: Here the two XSD (Request and Response)

http://Falcondmv.com/XSD/CoverageRequestDocument_00200809.xsd
http://Falcondmv.com/XSD/CoverageResponseDocument_00200809.xsd

Comment: What language are you writing this webservice and with which library? For example, java and axis2?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the language/library combination you plan on using I cannot give advice. However, in general there are two strategies:

- Languages like Java and .NET will let you generate classes from an XSD. This class will of course be serializable, so just make the classes the request and response contracts.
- WSDL is a superset of XSD, so if your soap library supports it, make the WSDL manually, have it import that XSD, and generate a stub service from it.